# is it possible an implementation pagination over graphql/express/node server side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-client

on the client-side(react/apollo) is not getting any pagination queries, is returning errors:

"message": "Cannot query field \"cursor\"

"message": "Unknown argument \"last\"

"message": "Cannot query field \"pageInfo\"

"message": "Unknown argument \"page\" on

This is how I did my model, queries and mutations schemas on the server side(node/express/mongoogse):

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  identification: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, unique: true },
  name: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  status: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  username: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  roleid: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  description: { type: String, trim: true },
  email: { type: String, trim: true, unique: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Shema:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    identification: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { type: GraphQLString },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    roleid: { type: GraphQLID },
    role: {
      type: RoleType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Role.findById(parent.roleid);
      },
    },
  }),
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    users: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return User.find();
      },
    },
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return User.findById(args.id);
      },
    },
  },
});


const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    addUser: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        identification: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
        status: { type: GraphQLString },
        username: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
        description: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        roleid: { type: GraphQLID },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return bcrypt
          .hash(args.password, 12)
          .then((hashedPassword) => {
            let user = new User({
              identification: args.identification,
              name: args.name,
              lastName: args.lastName,
              status: args.status,
              username: args.username,
              password: hashedPassword,
              description: args.description,
              email: args.email,
              roleid: args.roleid,
            });
            return user.save();
          })
          .then((result) => {
            return { ...result._doc, password: null, id: result.id };
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
      },
    },
    updateUser: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        identification: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
        status: { type: GraphQLString },
        username: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
        description: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        roleid: { type: GraphQLID },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return bcrypt
          .hash(args.password, 12)
          .then((hashedPassword) => {
            let user = User.findByIdAndUpdate(
              args.id,
              {
                identification: args.identification,
                name: args.name,
                lastName: args.lastName,
                status: args.status,
                username: args.username,
                password: hashedPassword,
                description: args.description,
                email: args.email,
                roleid: args.roleidupduu,
              },
              { new: true }
            );
            return user;
          })
          .then((result) => {
            return { ...result._doc, password: null, id: result.id };
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
      },
    },
    deleteUser: {
      type: UserType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return User.findByIdAndDelete(args.id);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fields have to be defined in your schema before they can be requested in a query. Arguments have to be defined in your schema before they can be used in a query as well. There is no built-in way to do pagination with GraphQL -- you have to add the appropriate types and arguments yourself.

If you're trying to build a Relay server, you may find it helpful to utilize [the official library](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js). If you're *not* building a Relay server, please bear in mind that you don't have to implement cursor-based pagination or connection types. If you're just starting out with GraphQL, you may want to get simple offset-based pagination working first before tackling more complex schema design patterns.